# Inheritance forced compile error

Tags: java, inheritance, compilation

Is there a posibility in having 3 classes, let's say A, B, and C, for which the following code in a test class will run like this:

```
 A a1 = new B(); // works
    A a2 = new C(); // works
    a1.method(); // works
    a2.method(); // compile error
```

Of course, i do not want writing errors in the a2.method to force the compile error.

Comment: Not if `a1` and `a2` both need to be declared as `A`.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. Declaring that something is an `A` means it must provide every method within `A`.

All you can do is over-ride the method and have it throw an exception to generate a runtime error if it is called.

Really this smells like you have your inheritance architecture wrong though and need to rethink it.